# LWC lightning-formatted-email - can you mix code and text in the VALUE

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

Inside my LWC JavaScript code, I was building my email and passing a very long string back to the LWC HTML and adding it to the lightning-formatted-email value. like: `"{emailAddr}?subject=hi {name}&body=hey {name}, click on the {url}"`

Is it possible in the LWC HTML for lightning-formatted-email to have the value intermix code and text together. Like so:

```
<lightning-formatted-email value={email}?subject=Email for {name}&body={name}, This is just to confirm our meeting, click on the URL to join {url} Thank You!" label="Send Email"></lightning-formatted-email>
```

Thanks so much for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

No. Unlike Aura, "expressions" are not allowed. You must calculate the value in your controller, then assign that value to the attribute:

```
<lightning-formatted-email value={emailString} label="Send Email"></lightning-formatted-email>
```

...

```
this.emailString = `${
  this.email
}?subject=Email for ${
  this.name
}&body=${
  this.name
}, This is just to confirm our meeting, click on the URL to join ${
  this.url
} Thank You!`;
```